# Could you help me to put files in the root folder in which there is launcher exe by using Jpackage?

Tags: java, jpackage

I want to generate the installer with jpackage but I'm not able to put the file in the same folder with launcher in exe type.

Add files in the same folder with launcher.

This is the structure that I want to do.

```
Name-Root-folder
   .\app
   .\Runtime
   .\launcher-name.exe
   .\icon-file.ico
   **.\others files //this what I want to put here in the root folder of the installed program.**
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

JPackage is an easy to use wrapper for native install systems. It allows a 'consistent' installation approach across platforms, yet the genrated installer is as native to the platform as possible. With that it implies some standards such as all application's resources to go into a lib folder.

It seems you want to deviate from that, which likely means jpackage is no longer the installer of choice.

JPackage is wrapping [wix](https://wixtoolset.org/) on the Windows platform so you could try to control this directly. Or make use of [NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page).